# Creating a Windows auto restart + a counter that increments each reboot

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to set up a program to auto restart windows after boot as well as incrementing the amount of restarts that it has completed.

I've written a small amount of code but it's not even restarting the system itself when placed in the startup folder. You can see the command prompt very briefly, then nothing happens.

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class AutoRestart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int numRestarts = 0;

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        numRestarts++;


        File outFile = new File("C:\\reboots\\numberOfReboots.txt");
        if (outFile.exists()) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        writer.println("Number of times rebooted: " + numRestarts);
        writer.close();

        r.exec("shutdown -r -t 0");
        System.out.println("Restarting. . .");

    }

}
```

Comment: Your app does exactly what you wrote it to do: It increments `numRestarts` to 1, which has nothing at all to do with how many reboots you've done so far (the variable, obviously, won't survive a reboot). You then check if that file exists and it does, your app exists. Thus, it does nothing.

Comment: It's set to autorun in the shell:startup folder, which my goal is to make it increment every time it boots up, but then it needs to save the file to the numberOfReboots.txt and then I need it to pull that number and set numRestarts to that number the next time it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int variable does not survive the reboot, you could try to read from the file you just created and increase the number in there.